# Get Caller Absolute Path - Bash Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: bash, path, jar, parameters

I am running a jar file from within an app bundle on Mac OS X Leopard. I need to pass into the jar a parameter. The parameter is the absolute path of the file which called the app bundle. I have my short bash script below. I know $0 gives the absolute path to the app bundle itself.

Does anyone know how to store in a variable the path I need (CALLERPATH below)? The current script listed works fine if another script calls it (find caller script in the reply from Dennis), but does not work the same when I double-click on "file.xyz".

Script 1

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $_
echo $(dirname $0)
echo $(basename $0)
echo $PWD
echo "$@"
echo $PPID
echo "My PPID echo"
myPPID=$PPID echo $(ps -p $myPPID -o args=)
BASEDIR=`dirname "$0"`
echo "CallerPath Output 1"
callerpath="$(/bin/ps -p $PPID -o args=)"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
echo "Caller Path Output 2"
callerpath="${callerpath#/bin/bash *}"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
echo "Final Caller Path"
callerpath="${callerpath%/*}"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
exec java \
-jar "$BASEDIR/../Resources/Java/myJar.jar" "$callerpath"
```

Output 1

```
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/myScript
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/myScript
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] myScript
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] / 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] -psn_0_766139 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] 63 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] My PPID echo 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] ps: Invalid process id: -o 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] ps: illegal argument: args= 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]] 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496]           [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]] 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496]           [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]] 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496]        ps [-L] 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] CallerPath Output 1 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] Caller Path Output 2 
9/25/09 3:54:42 PM [0x0-0xbb0bb].MyApp[1496] Final Caller Path
```

Script 2

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $_
echo $(dirname $0)
echo $(basename $0)
echo $PWD
echo "$@"
echo $PPID
echo "My PPID export"
export myPPID=$PPID
echo $(ps -p $myPPID -o args=)
BASEDIR=`dirname "$0"`
echo "CallerPath Output 1"
callerpath="$(/bin/ps -p $PPID -o args=)"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
echo "Caller Path Output 2"
callerpath="${callerpath#/bin/bash *}"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
echo "Final Caller Path"
callerpath="${callerpath%/*}"
echo -e "$callerpath\n"
exec java \
-jar "$BASEDIR/../Resources/Java/myJar.jar" "$callerpath"
```

Output 2

```
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/myScript
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS/myScript
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] /Applications/appBundle.app/Contents/MacOS 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] myScript
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] / 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] -psn_0_790721 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] 63 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] My PPID export 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] CallerPath Output 1 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] Caller Path Output 2 
9/25/09 4:02:40 PM [0x0-0xc10c1].MyApp[1561] Final Caller Path
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac, so I cannot use the **$(readlink -f $0)** trick. Here is my solution, please test it against your system as I don't have a Linux machine handy:

```
# Get absolute path of the script
dir=`dirname $0`            # The directory where the script is 
pushd "$dir" > /dev/null    # Go there
CALLERPATH=$PWD             # Record the absolute path
popd > /dev/null            # Return to previous dir

echo $CALLERPATH
```

## How does it work?

The strategy is 1) get the dir name, 2) cd to it, and 3) record the $PWD, which is always in absolute path format.

Comment: I do not have a Linux system either, I am running this script on Mac OS X Leopard. If you push $0 onto the stack and navigate there, then store the $PWD, you just get the directory of app bundle again. I need the path of the file which called the app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a kludge, but here goes:

First, your tags include "bash", but your shebang is for `/bin/sh`. I'm assuming Bash.

First caller:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/username/dirONE/calltest a b c
```

Next calltest:

```
#!/bin/bash
# echo some stuff to get our bearings
echo $0
echo $_                                  # should be the same as $0
echo $(dirname $0)
echo $(basename $0)
echo $PWD
echo "$@"
echo $PPID                               # parent process ID
# start making $callerpath, if there are spaces in a dirname or script name, they should be preserved
callerpath="$(ps -p $PPID -o args=)"     # get the command name of the parent (it may have args after it)
callerpath="${callerpath#/bin/bash *}"   # strip /bin/bash from the beginning
callerpath="${callerpath%/*}"            # like dirname, but removes the args, too
echo "$callerpath"
```

Now to run the test:

```
$ cd /home/username/dirTHREE
$ /home/username/dirTWO/caller 1 2 3
/home/username/dirONE/calltest
/home/username/dirONE/calltest
/home/username/dirONE
calltest
/home/username/dirTHREE
a b c
32674
/home/username/dirTWO
```

Comment: This test code returns simply a "/" character as my caller path. I do not know why, because I am not framiliar with all the bash syntax

Comment: What does `ps -p $PPID -o args=` produce (include it on a line by itself in the "calltest" script)?

Comment: I initially tried to just copy the "callpath=" lines into my above script. But when I ran it as you wrote your post, as two scripts, it gives me ": command not foundltest: line 9:"...maybe there is a syntax error? And were you assuming this was a script calling the bundle? As clarification, my app bundle is being called from a file of my own registered file extension. So i double click "file.xyz", launch manager knows my app is the owner, and gives me the abs path to that file. i dont know how mac handles that path (the "open" command in windows usually has "%1" as the abs path).

Comment: I cut out the comments and such, so the error line was the ps -p $PPID -o args=

Comment: $PWD placed in my script above returns "/"...probably because my app bundle resides in /Applications. The "$@" returns "-psn_0_" with a random number after the last underscore. The $PPID doesnt echo anything to the screen.

Comment: You need to change your shebang to "`#!/bin/bash`" if you haven't. Your `/bin/sh` may not have the $PPID environment variable. "And were you assuming this was a script calling the bundle?" I am assuming that the script in your question is called by something. That something is its parent. The parent's process ID is $PPID. What do `echo $PPID` and `ps -p $PPID -o args=` produce at a Bash prompt?

Comment: I changed the shebang as you said to a Bash prompt. I do get a number for $PPID, which of course changes every run. but still get the command not found errors when trying to set callerpath.

Comment: Please add to your question post your test script which includes the callerpath lines and add a comment to the line which produces the error.

Comment: I posted in my question both scripts and the output from the terminal. Thank you for your continued effort on this issue.

Comment: First try: `dos2unix yourscriptname`. If that fixes it then ignore this>>> I think you're running into a Unicode or other character encoding or a line ending problem. At a Bash prompt, try 1) pasting in the line that has the `ps` in it, 2) hand entering that same line, 3) if you get errors on both of those try hand typing: `test=$(ls)` If you get an error on #1 but not #2 then it's an encoding or line-ending problem. If both have errors, but not #3 then it's something else. One of the reasons I think it's a line ending problem is that the error messages appear to have overwritten themselves.

Comment: You were correct in that there was extra space at the end of some lines in the calltest script. The calltest script now works. I reposted in my question the current script in my app bundle and the console output. Nothing is being echoed for the caller path and no errors reported. I do not know who technically is the parent process when I double click "file.xyz". Would the parent be the file itself, which isnt a script, or would the parent be the Launch Manager and that somehow complicates things? I feel this is very close, thanks again for your continued input.

Comment: Change all your `echo "$callerpath"` lines to `echo -e "$callerpath\n"` and add `ps -p $PPID -o args=` under `echo $PPID` and post the result. (Those `echo "$callerpath"` lines should have produced blank lines in the output if `$callerpath` is null, rather than nothing at all.) I'm particularly interested in seeing the output of `ps`. Please also run that `ps` command at a shell prompt and post its output.

Comment: The script code is updated as well as the output, and the ps command from the terminal by itself. The output did not change when double-clicking the file (only the psn changed). Odd that the "ps -p $PPID -o args=" produced nothing in the output.

Comment: Everywhere there's a `ps` add its full path, likely `/bin`, so they look like `/bin/ps...` - you can do `type -a ps` or `which ps` to find out where it is.

Comment: using the "type -a ps" command in the app bundle script returns "ps is /bin/ps". Still no output when changing to "/bin/ps -p $PPID -o args=". I know this is probably getting frustrating haha.

Comment: After days of researching this, I may have abandon this route. All over now I am seeing that "Java + SWT + Mac OS X app bundle + getting the caller path = pretty much impossible". They say Apple is ALL event based and you cannot get file path parameters through the command line in the context that i want it (only through an event handle). I have some ideas for work around programmatically I may have to live with until a bridge to apple events is available again. Once again thank you for all your attempts.

Comment: Change the line under `echo $PPID` to `echo $(ps -p $PPID -o args=)` and see what it prints out. It doesn't make any sense that `basename` and `dirname` produce output and `ps` doesn't. You might even experiment with other executables like `ls`, `date`, `uname` or `tty`. I wonder if there's another character encoding or stray character problem. It seems too close for me to be willing to quit. I love a good puzzle.

Comment: I am willing to keep going to solve it haha. I updated the script again and output in the post. Its interesting that echo $(ps) produces an output and echo $(ps -p $PPID -o args=) produces no output. Maybe the script cannot access the parent? Not sure.

Comment: Try `myPPID=$PPID echo $(ps -p $myPPID -o args=)` (all on one line - note "my" in two places). If that doesn't work, try `export myPPID=$PPID` on one line, then the next line: `echo $(ps -p $myPPID -o args=)`

Comment: Both scripts and outputs are posted above. First one provided an error in syntax, the other no output at all.

Comment: I will be heading out shortly for the weekend and we can continue this saga monday if you like. can post some suggestions you come up with and i will try them out then. have a good weekend dennis.

Comment: Go back and test this stuff (the various iterations we've gone through) using the "caller" and "calltest" scripts in a Terminal instead of from your app bundle, making sure to fix the line endings and trying the variations on `ps`. Skip the myPPID tests. Also, change your echoes to wrap some text around the arguments, for example: `echo "+++$(ps -p $myPPID -o args=)---"` and `echo "+++${callerpath}---"` (note the removal of the `-e` and `\n` and addition of `{}`).